# Using TRIMMEAN function with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am having trouble putting together a formula that returns the TRIMMEAN value that fits multiple conditions.

The 'Output' table (screenshot attached) needs to read the data in the 'Dataset' table (screenshot attached), and give back e.g. the trimmean (av excl outliers) of the Quantity of P1020 where Size = S... and so and so forth for all the cells/conditions in the Output table.

I have so far tried `=TRIMMEAN(IF(($B$2:$B$14=F2)*($A$2:$A$14=G1),C2:C14),10%`) But its returning the average of the entire array instead of looking at only the rows where the Product Size is S and Product code is P1020.

**Dataset :**

[image]

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your function is correct, you just need to convert it to an Array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

[image: Array formula]

Below is an example of your original formula referring to two "filtered" rows of data (S - P1020). You will see that the result is the same (10.5):

[image: Filtered rows]

I hope it helps.